# A simple way to implement pathfinding using bullet physics - iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have bullet physics set up and working on the iPhone but now I want to implement some sort of path finding with it.

The problem is I have no idea where to start, the level is pretty simple just a lot of pillars that I want the 'bad guys' to navigate around to get to the player character.

Do you have any suggestions or are there any tutorials you recommend for pathfinding using this on the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use A* (and optionally OpenSteer).

- A* for ObjC: http://bravobug.com/news/?p=118
- OpenSteer http://opensteer.sourceforge.net/
- XNA sample http://www.stevecavanagh.com/portfolio/12/opensteer-plugins